# Displaying image in foreach blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-blade, crud

So, I am trying to display image, here is how i create my data

```
public function create_supplier(Supplier $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validated();

        $extension = $request->file('logoimg')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = $request->supplier_name . '.' . $extension;
        $request->file('logoimg')->storeAs('/storage/supplier_logo/', $filename);

        $supplier = ModelsSupplier::create([
            'supplier_name' => $request->supplier_name,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
            'logoimg' => $request->logoimg
        ]);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Supplier successfully added', 'supplier' => $supplier]);
    }
```

Now, I want to display the logo img in blade.php

```
<tbody>
                @foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$supplier->id}}</td>
                    <td><img src="{{ asset('storage/supplier_logo/' . $supplier->logoimg) }}" alt="test"></td>
                    <td>{{$supplier->supplier_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$supplier->address}}</td>
                    <td>{{$supplier->email}}</td>
                    <td>{{$supplier->phone_number}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

it has successfully display the supplier_name, address, etc. but it shows the alt text that is "test".  the file has also been successfully added to my storage/supplier_logo.

however, this is the value in my phpmyadmin,
C:\xampp\tmp\php15CC.tmp

please do help, thank you!

Comment: Sounds like `$request->logoimg` is the temporary name of the file prior to its ending location. Not familiar with framework but is `$request->logoimg` correct or should it be `$filename`... or `'/storage/supplier_logo/' . $filename`

Comment: `storeAs('/storage/supplier_logo/', $filename)` - Looks ok! `asset('storage/supplier_logo/' . $supplier->logoimg)` - Whats is `$supplied->logoimg`?  Looks like `'logoimg' => $request->logoimg`; is that the same as `$filename`? Did you do any debugging to make sure the same filename is used when storing **AND** referencing the images?

Comment: Did you try to check the value of `$request->logoimg` when saving? Does the file exist on the path? And then check the value of `{{ asset('storage/supplier_logo/' . $supplier->logoimg) }}`? Do they match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to save image url that saved on disk into your database  , not the $request->logoimg .

storeAs() return the file path

```
$filepath = $request->file('logoimg')->storeAs('/storage/supplier_logo/', $filename);

$supplier = ModelsSupplier::create([
    'supplier_name' => $request->supplier_name,
    'address' => $request->address,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
    'logoimg' => $filepath
]);
```

i dont test the code , maybe you need some debug

Comment: You're close, but you'd likely want to use `$filepath = '/storage/supplier_logo/', $filename;`, then `$request->file('logoimg')->storeAs($filepath)`, then finally `'logoimg' => $filepath`. I'm not sure what the `storeAs()` method actually returns (documentation says `string|false`, but it might not be the same as `/storage/supplier_logo/' . $filename`, i.e. things added, etc.)

Comment: @TimLewis storeAs return the saved path   https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem check the link and search about that

Comment: I know that, and the correct link would be https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html#method_storeAs or https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php#L84, but what I'm trying to say is it might return something that is not `'/storage/supplier_logo/', $filename`; i.e. the full filesystem path, like `C:\Users\xampp\laravel\storage\supplier_logo\example.png`, or similar, which likely will not work when used with the `asset()` helper. Or it could just work; I don't have a way to verify is all I'm saying 